# Require api to search for company information

Tags: iphone, ios

Hi i am new into IOS development, I have requirement from my client that he **wants to search for particular company name in particular city and in particular country**.

The query would be like

> "company name +city + country name".

Can anyone suggest me is there some **kind of API available** for this kind of query. Any help would be appreciated.
thanks

Comment: Can you please add more information to your question? Please narrow down the query. Its a broad query.

Comment: I require some kind of google api where i can make this query and in results i will get its phonenumber, website etc.